# Best method for clustering job titles

Tags: r, clustering

I have a vector of occupations like :
*input <- c("farmer","actuarial analyst","agricultural assistant","bank teller","software engineer","chemical engineer",etc)*

what I would like to do is cluster all related occupations together. I managed to find reference clusters from https://www.onetonline.org/find/career which also has the most common job titles found under each cluster. I saved all of these in a data frame which I named ref_cl where each column is cluster (a csv file can be downloaded from the link provided after selecting "all career clusters" from the drop down).

To clean up the dataframe I created a function that takes in a cluster of occupations and returns all unique bigrams in a character vector:

```
unique_bigrams=function(char_vect){
       char_vect=as.data.frame(na.omit(char_vec))
       bigram=char_vec %>% unnest(cols="char_vec") %>%
           unnest_tokens(bigrams,char_vecs,token="ngrams",n=2) %>%
             separate(bigrams,c("w1","w2"),sep=" ") %>%
              filter(!w1 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
              filter(!w2 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
              unite(bigrams,w1,w2,sep=" ")
              bigram=unique(bigram$bigrams)
              return(bigram)
      }
```

My thought process to cluster the members of *input* is to use a string similarity metric and compare each member of *input* to the members of a cluster and if the resultant metric is less than a certain threshold value I add that particular occupation from *input* to a list. I used a for loop to accomplish this:

```
L=list()
  for (i in 1:ncol(refcl)) {
    ref=unique_bigram(refcl[,i])
    for (j in 1:length(input)) {
       temp=expand.grid(ref,input[j])
       colnames(temp)=c("v1","v2")
       temp$dist=stringdist(temp$v1,temp$v2,method = "jw") #calculate dist
       d=temp$dist[temp$dist<0.3] #subset
       if(length(d)>0){
           L[[i]]=input[j] #store the jth element in the ith cluster (list object)
    } #endif
  }#end inner for
    ind=which(input %in% L[[i]])
    input=input[-ind] #updates the input vector by deleting already clustered occupations
} #end outer for
```

The problem is, I am getting a great deal of classification error which leads me to think I am using the wrong the distance measure (I am using the Jaro-Winkler distance). Does anyone have any advice as to how I can go about this problem; should I even be using a distance measure to begin with or should I be focusing on clustering the input vector without using a reference list?

Comment: I'd recommend against using statistical functions here and instead, rely on known taxonomies of job to high-level-job categorizations.  For example, the Bureau of Labor Statistics uses NAICS and Standard Occupational Classification (SOC) codes to lump industries and occupations togther: 
https://www.census.gov/topics/employment/industry-occupation/guidance/code-lists.html.  Have you considered using this instead of "rolling your own?"

Comment: I have not considered this approach; The current dataset I am working on is small compared to what is coming once I develop a method of grouping together the occupations hence my reasoning for trying some machine learning approach. I understand that brown clustering is way to go about it but I am unsure if this is done in R at the moment; any thoughts?

Comment: If you have much more data coming, that's even more reason to simply use a look-up function from the standard BLS codes.  A lookup should be more efficient than any agglomerative, hierarchical clustering algorithm.  I am not familiar with any R packages that support the Brown Clustering Algorithm, but many seems to exist in python and could easily adapted.